# Question about a double integral

Tags: integration

I would like to evaluate the following integral:

$$I = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2π} e^{i(m_1 a \cos φ + m_2 b \sin φ)r}δ(k^2 - r^2)r dr dφ$$

The answer that is provided after performing the integration over $r$ is:

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2π}e^{i k \sqrt{(m_1 a)^2 + (m_2 b)^2} \cos φ} dφ$$

As a first step I wrote:

$$δ(k^2 - r^2) = \frac{1}{2k}[δ(k-r) + δ(k+r)]$$

which leads to:

$$I =  \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2π}e^{i k (m_1 a \cos φ + m_2 b \sin φ)} dφ$$

I'm not quite sure how to proceed further. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Use $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(\theta-\alpha)$

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you very much. This identity completely slipped my mind.